# Ubuntu 20.04 setting up 2 network interface on 2 differents subnet (1 WAN and 1 LAN)

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu-20.04, netplan

I got a vm (on proxmox) to which I passthrough 2 physical NIC.

- ens16f0: LAN connected (which is behind a routeur connected to a different WAN)
- ens16f1: WAN directly connected

Both work as they should if configured individually, but when I try to set up netplan to make both work as I want, I only got the ens16f1 working,inbound and outbound.  If I ping WAN ips or WAN domain name, everything worked.
But nothing works from or to the ens16f0.

Here is the neplan yaml file (obviously, ips were changed)

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
        ens16f0:
                addresses: [192.168.1.36/24]
                nameservers:
                        addresses: [192.168.1.18]
                routes: 
                        - to: 192.168.1.0/24
                          via: 192.168.1.1
                          table: 101
                routing-policy:
                        - from: 192.168.1.0/24
                          table: 101
                          priority: 300
        ens16f1:
                addresses: [140.140.140.180/29]
                nameservers:
                        addresses: [1.1.1.1,1.0.0.1]
                routes: 
                        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
                          via: 140.140.140.177
                          table: 102
                routing-policy:
                        - from: 0.0.0.0/0
                          table: 102
                          priority: 350
```

Here is the output of `ip a`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens16f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b5:2a:72:da:d2:5d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s16f0
    inet 192.168.1.36/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global ens16f0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::be2a:72ff:fcdc:d25d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens16f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:2f:b1:df:d2:2a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s16f1
    inet 140.140.140.180/29 brd 140.140.140.183 scope global ens16f1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::be2a:72ff:fcdc:d25e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Here is the output of `ip route`:

```
140.140.140.176/29 dev ens16f1 proto kernel scope link src 140.140.140.180 
192.168.1.0/24 dev ens16f0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.36
```